# Elasticsearch query shortest match

Tags: elasticsearch

I search "AB" in elasticsearch

result: "ABB" is in front of "AB"(score ABB > AB)

I want "AB" > "ABB"

```
{
    'sort': [{'_score': {'order': 'desc'}}],
    'from': _from,
    'size': page_size,
    'query': {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": key,
            "type": "best_fields",
            "fields": ["name^5", "intro"]
        }
    }
}

"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {

            "intro": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
           "name": {
               "type": "text",
               "fields": {
                   "keyword": {
                       "ignore_above": 256,
                       "type": "keyword"
                   }
               }
           },
           "id": {
               "type": "long"
           },
        }
    }
}
```

My data is Chinese

Such as : 
    name: 刘佳     intro: "xxxxxx"
    name: 刘佳佳   intro: "xxxxxx"

Comment: Which field holds value **AB** and **ABB**. Do both these values of `name` field or one is of `name` and other of `intro`. Please share the mapping and documents which hold these values. Then only it can be determined why **ABB** is scored more since one field i.e. `name` has higher boost than `intro`

Answer (score 1):

If ABB is rarer in your corpus than AB, then ABB will have a better score since default scoring use TF/IDF formula.

If you want to boost a field a query time based on the field length, first you need to store the field length in another field ( using painless and a pipeline or before indexing your data ). Then you will be able to use a function_score_query ( see here the [field value factor function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) ) with a `log2p` modifier to take count of your field length